# Import Chrome settings when sync is disabled and no admin

Tags: windows, google-chrome, sync

I'm in a corporate (Windows) environment and I can use Chrome.  Sync is disabled and I don't have write access to the registry, so I can't use the answers from this question: [Sync Chrome bookmarks without admin access](https://superuser.com/q/937655/85694).  I can create bookmarks, install extensions, etc., but I have to do it manually like a savage.  Is there a way to sync settings without sync?  Like over sneakernet?